# HTTP compression in Apache reverse proxy?

Tags: proxy, reverse-proxy, apache-2.4, compression, gzip

I have an App server where Apache httpd is installed which serves the requests. We have another Proxy machine which redirects the requests to this App Server httpd using proxy pass.

When I apply gzip in **App Server level** its **working** fine. But, When I try to implement the same on the **other Proxy machine httpd**, at the same time removing gzip code from App Server httpd, the gzip is **not Working**.

I am trying to implement gzip in the **other proxy machine** than the one it resides on(App Server) because when the content is served to the front end its giving **mixed content error** as its being served over http rather than https

The content we are serving is relative path but when compressed its becoming absolute path thats why we are getting mixed content error. Anyway we can tackle this problem? If then , i can implement it on my app server level itself

Can anyone help? If needed anymore info please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

It's a relatively basic configuration -- just load mod_deflate and configure it (SetOutputfilter, AddOutputFilterByType, etc) as the manual for mod_deflate describes.

Comment: Note specifically that if the proxied documents are of some unusual MIME type like application/json or text/xml, you'll need to add those to the AddOutputFilterByType line.

Comment: Thanks. I have actually resolved the issue. It was something i missed out related to the proxy url setup in my WordPress database. Thanks for all your help.